# Markov Chains and First Return Time

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes

I'm having a difficult time with discrete Markov Chains. In particular, I need help with part c, d, and e on this problem. I do not understand how you can directly calculate the expected first return time to state 6 in part c, how to calculate the probability that the first return time to 6 is finite given you start in state 5, and the probability that the first return time to 6 is finite given you start in state 3. Any help would be great, thanks!

Here is a picture to the problem. By the way, P is the transition probability matrix for X where X is a Markov Chain with state space S={1,2,3,4,5,6}.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Zk8X9.jpg?1]

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If you start in $\lbrace 4,5,6\rbrace$, you stay in $\lbrace 4,5,6\rbrace$, and you have a $1/3$ chance to move to $6$ at each step.

Comment: Ok so for part d), would I condition on the first step? So my probability becomes the sum of P[T6<inf|X1=k,X0=4]P[X1=k|X0=4] from k=4 to 6?